# Why isn't audio rendering?

Tags: rendering, audio

Using the VSE, I have included a strip of audio, the "scene" that I animated, and other video footage. I have been able to hear the audio in playback, however after rendering I cannot hear any audio.

I have used multiple combinations for codecs, the one in the image below among others. An audio codec HAS been selected for all of them, but none of my rendered results have rendered audio.

[image: render audio settings]

Comment: Just to make it clear, without changing anything in the file, if you press ALT-A you hear the sound, but if you render the animation with CTRL F12 to a file that supports audio with proper settings there is no sound when you play the file with (eg) VLC? If you import the resulting file rendered into a new blender file, the VSE shows an audio track? and it has a waveform if you choose to visualize it?

Comment: For your first question, that is correct. I followed your suggestion and imported the resulting file into a new file, and the VSE did show an audio track (and it did have a waveform).

Comment: And still, when you play it in VLC or another media player you hear no sound? Really weird. It sounds like some codec playback problem on you pc, maybe. When you use ALT+A sound is not yet encoded, this can explain why you hear it only in this way. VLC shows info about audio/video streams, while they are playing (even paused) see under tools/codec information, you could get some hint even from tools/messages.

Answer (score 1):

m.ardito suggestion have worked for me. Ive had the same issue where there was no audio in rendered file. Than I realised that I can not hear audio also while scrubbing in Video Sequence Editor. Simple ALT+A have returned everything to normal.