# Output vs Format vs Codec: what is the right combination?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, audio

### Context

My problem started with a **partial** lack of sound in my rendered file. The `WAV` audio strips were missing from the output, while the `AAC` audio from a `.mp4` video file was present. Everything is audible when editing.

There are some related questions which taught me that it's a problem of codec selection. This one and its answer motivated my further investigation and my question: [I can't render audio with my video](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32245/i-cant-render-audio-with-my-video?lq=1)

I had the following for the output settings because I thought `MP3` is a good selection which would work on all computers (I am using Blender 2.77 on a Ubuntu 14.04 derivative (Mint) and I have `libmp3lame` installed)

[image: blender output settings]

I solved my problem by changing the Audio Codec to `AAC`.

---

### I am looking for:

1. Explanation of why with `MP3` output the `WAV` sound is missing but the `AAC` sound is audible
2. Understanding the differences between selections in `Output` section: `MPEG` vs `H.264` since these seem to be the most common. Other formats are welcome :) (`Frame server`, `XVid`, `AVI Raw|JPEG`).
3. Explanation of `Encoding > Format` and `Encoding > Codec` options, in relation to point 2. For example, why are you able to choose `MPEG` output and `non-MPEG` format and `non-MPEG-non-<format>` codec? This is **VERY** confusing.

I hope I won't be closed as being too broad, I tried to be as specific as possible.

I realise this may not be a blender specific question. Please advise where to look for additional information.

---

### Related questions:

Some of these are experiencing problems similar to mine (lack of sound) and usually due to a misconfiguration of `Output` and `Encoding` sections. However, even those that are solved give a very specific answer and are of little help when you're problem is *slightly* different

[Sound works in Blender, but no sound in the final render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50883/when-i-render-my-video-no-sound)

This one gives one choice that is working, but no explanation: [Rendering Sound In Video Sequencer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39465/rendering-sound-in-video-sequencer)  (duplicate https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47816/how-do-i-render-intros-in-blender-with-sound )

This one reports a problem when converting `FLAC` to `MP3`. It could be related to my initial problem, since both `FLAC` and `WAV` are lossless https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38850/script-for-audio-encoding

[Can I incorporate audio into my output avi render?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47269/can-i-incorporate-audio-into-my-output-avi-render)

[Why isn't audio rendering?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43037/why-isnt-audio-rendering)

[No audio output in rendered video file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21278/no-audio-output-in-rendered-video-file)

[VSE: How to render a video with audio?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24357/vse-how-to-render-a-video-with-audio)

Maybe: [No sound in VSE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14509/no-sound-in-vse)

Comment: You might probably split your question into three separate linked questions.

Comment: thanks, I'll do that. Here is the one related to the first part: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52335/no-sound-from-wav-strip-when-encoding-in-mp3-but-ok-from-aac-strip

Answer (score 2):

**1** - `Explanation of why with MP3 output the WAV sound is missing but the AAC sound is audible`
this could be a problem with that particular file, try converting it to mp3 using an external program like ffmpeg or audacity or even an [online tool](http://audio.online-convert.com/convert-to-mp3).
or try a matroska container with x264 video codec and mp3 audio codec.

**2** - `Understanding the differences between selections in Output section: MPEG vs H.264 since these seem to be the most common. Other formats are welcome :) (Frame server, XVid, AVI Raw|JPEG).`

**3** - `Explanation of Encoding > Format and Encoding > Codec options, in relation to point 2. For example, why are you able to choose MPEG output and non-MPEG format and non-MPEG-non-<format> codec? This is VERY confusing.`

a container like (mp4,mkv) contains n video streams and n audio streams encoded in a given format with a given codec,a codec is a **co**der and **dec**oder.
think of a container like a .zip or .rar file
some containers don't allow certain combination of those codecs (like .webm can't have a video stream encoded in h.264 but allows a vp9).

blender offers you presets to make your life easier.
a mpeg-4 (.mp4) with h.264 and mp3 like in your screenshot is a valid combination and the reason h264 is common is because it produces better video quality with small sizes and is well supported by browsers and Operating systems.

Comment: 1 - I tried your suggestion and the conversion works with ffmpeg and the online tool. The matrosk+h264 combination presents the same problems. See the linked question in my comment to this one.

2&3 - thanks, I like the .zip comparison. It still doesn't make much sense why you can encode `h.264` in an `mp4` container or vice-versa, but I guess it's more flexible this way