# No sound from WAV strip when encoding in MP3 (but ok from AAC strip)

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

Breaking down a bigger question: [Output vs Format vs Codec: what is the right combination?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52281/output-vs-format-vs-codec-what-is-the-right-combination)

In the same project, I have a `WAV` sound-only strip originating from a recording and an `AAC` sound strip coming from an `MP4` video.
I am overlaying the WAV on top of a picture and then concatenating the `video+aac` strips.
I am sure both are 'visible' (not muted) and they are audible when previewing in the editor:

[image: layout of strips in blender]

When I try to render them into a file containing `MP3` audio, only the last part (the `AAC` sound) is audible. When the sound encoder is `AAC`, both work correctly and can be heard in the result.

I tried various combinations of containers and codecs, all fail to render the first part to `MP3`.

I am using Blender 2.77 on Linux Mint 17.2 (Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 derivative) and I have `libmp3lame` installed. There is no problem with the `WAV` file, it can successfully be converted to `MP3` using `ffmpeg` or online tools.

Comment: Have you tried previous versions of Blender and is this a consistent problem occuring with different source files (cc0-licensed/public domain everyone can use for testing) as well?